# I want to write php to add json to packages

Tags: php, json

I want to write php to add information to json id packages.
I want it to be in the same area.
Sorry that I typed English is not good. I use translation.

My code:-

```
<?php
$donatename = $_POST['donatename'];
$donateURL = $_POST['donateurl'];
    $json1_str = '{
        "transaction": "'.$fti_u.'",
        "donatename": "'.$donatename.'",
        "donateURL": "'.$donateURL.'",
        "releaseddate": "'.$fttime_u.'"
    }';

$json1 = json_decode($json1_str, true);
$json2['packages'][] = $json1;
$jsonData = json_encode($json2, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

file_put_contents('data.json', $jsonData, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

--- output i am getting currently ---

```
{
    "packages": [
        {
            "transaction": "",
            "donatename": "",
            "donateURL": "",
            "releaseddate": ""
        }
    ]
}{
    "packages": [
        {
            "transaction": "",
            "donatename": "",
            "donateURL": "",
            "releaseddate": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

----Expected -----

```
{
    "packages": [
        {
            "transaction": "",
            "donatename": "",
            "donateURL": "",
            "releaseddate": ""
        },
        {
            "transaction": "",
            "donatename": "",
            "donateURL": "",
            "releaseddate": ""
        }
,        {
            "transaction": "",
            "donatename": "",
            "donateURL": "",
            "releaseddate": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Error:

> Parse error on line 10: ...""        }    ]}{    "packages": [
>   --------------------^ Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'

Comment: You are appending your single json block to a file every time your script is executed. Instead you should execute script once and use foreach to collect packages and give it to json object.
Alternatively you need to read from file every time, convert to array, append to array, convert back to json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add the data to the existing content, so just read the existing data file, add the new content and overwrite the existing file with the new version of the data...

```
$json1 = json_decode($json1_str, true);
// Load existing content
$json2 = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'), true);
$json2['packages'][] = $json1;
$jsonData = json_encode($json2, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

file_put_contents('data.json', $jsonData);  // Remove the append
```

Comment: This is what I want. You may not be an ordinary person reading my message. Hahaha. Thank you

Comment: I ask another question. How do I record it from above?

Comment: Sorry - not sure what you mean.

Comment: Save json on top Instead of recording from bottom

Comment: Change `$json2['packages'][] = $json1;` to `array_unshift($json2['packages'], $json1);`